# Change background color of one worksheet using action filter from another in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

So I'm making this tableau dashboard where I have multiple sheets with pie charts and text content. The action filter of one of the worksheets that has a pie chart pass on to the worksheet that contains text . Now what I want that as I select one of the two sub parts of the pie chart(YES/NO) , the background color of the worksheet that contains the text should change as RED/GREEN and the default color of this worksheet should be Blue .

Thanks

Comment: Action filters cannot change the style of a worksheet. They can be used to filter or invoke a URL action.

Comment: But then , what is the alternate solution to this problem

Comment: Filters can't be used in calculated fields so manipulation can't be achieved but we can manipulate using parameters

Comment: Here's a very creative way to do it with filters. I don't know how to make it work with action filters but it should get you started in the right direction: https://community.tableau.com/ideas/5287